# React pending promise while after fetching from express backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a simple node.js express server like so:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ express: 'YOUR EXPRESS BACKEND IS CONNECTED TO REACT' });
});
```

and have the proxy set up in the package.json like so:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
```

However, in my App.js, I try to fetch the JSON from the server, but it returns me a pending promise (I found this out with a console.log in the .then()).  How could I fix this so that it properly fetches the string in the express JSON object?

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {data: "asdf"};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/express_backend')
      .then(res => this.setState({data: res.express}));
  }
```

I am running both `node server.js` and `npm start` at this time.

Comment: fetch('/express_backend')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({data: res.express}));

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) a good write-up on how fetch returns data.

> The response of a fetch() request is a Stream object, which means that when we call the json() method, a Promise is returned since the reading of the stream will happen asynchronously.

So you need to call the `json()` method, which returns a promise, first.

```
fetch('/express_backend')
  .then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(res.statusText);
    }
    return res.json()
  })
  .then(res => this.setState({data: res.express}))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: I'm now getting `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`.  I'll give the linked article a read now!

Comment: You might be hitting an error, I added error handling to the code that might help track down what's going on

Comment: Oddly, no error is being thrown and the setState line is triggering the JSON.parse error in the console.